# How to get two models data in for loop with filter: Django

Tags: django, django-models

I do have two model as below, like patient details model and patient visit model. I want to list the visits of all patients (if exist). in views.py I am passing both models data by get all. how to filter and show it in the template by using for loop. I am using two for loop it shows total number of patient multiply total number of visit which is wrong..

```
class patientprofile(models.Model):

pat_Fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
pat_Lname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
def IntegerField(self):
    return self.id



class visits(models.Model):
pat_ID = models.ForeignKey(patientprofile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
visit_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
visit_time = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False)
```

views.py

```
@login_requireddef visitslist(request):
patpro=patientprofile.objects.all()
vis=visits.objects.all()
return render(request, 'pmp/visitslist.html', {'vis':vis, 'patpro':patpro})
```

Template as below

```
{% for a in vis %}              
                                               
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    {{ a.visit_time }}
                                                </td>
                                                <td>{{ a.visit_date }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ patpro.id }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ patpro.pat_Fname }}</td>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily transform it into a `dict` object using `values()` function in queryset object.
for example:

```
merged_tables_dict = visits.objects.values('visit_date', 'visit_time', 'pat_ID__pat_Fname', 'pat_ID__pat_Lname')
```

That will return a list of objects with all data in values params

You can read more about it [Django Docs values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values)

Comment: will it work in template for loop?. could your please elaborate it?

Comment: `values()` Returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries, rather than model instances, when used as an iterable.

Each of those dictionaries represents an object, with the keys corresponding to the attribute names of model objects.
This example compares the dictionaries of values() with the normal model objects:
>>> Blog.objects.filter(name__startswith='Beatles')
<QuerySet [<Blog: Beatles Blog>]>
>>> Blog.objects.filter(name__startswith='Beatles').values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Beatles Blog', 'tagline': 'All the latest Beatles news.'}]>